# XamForms.Controls.Calendar in Xamarin.Forms initially showing October 2013

Tags: xamarin, calendar, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, calendarview

I am a newbie to `Xamarin.Forms developer`, in my `Application` I am showing `calendar` view. for this purpose I used this https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar plugin for my application. This plugin(Custom Calendar) is working fine except one small `UI issue`. At the time of showing calendar it is initially loading with **October,2013** default value then showing the current `Month` in Calendar. Please help me to resolve the issue.

**DateSelection.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TestApp.DateSelection"
        xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:CareValet;assembly=CareValet"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XamForms.Controls;assembly=XamForms.Controls.Calendar"        
        Title="Date Selection">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" 
                        iOS="20, 40, 20, 20"
                        Android="20, 20, 20, 20"
                        WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
        </ContentPage.Padding>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <RelativeLayout>

            //.....My Code....
                    <controls:Calendar x:Name="calender" Padding="10,0,10,0" StartDay="Sunday" DateClicked="DateClicked" 
                         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
                        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0,Constant=200}"
                        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=selectDateText, Property=Y, Factor=1, Constant=25}" 
                    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width, Factor=0}"></controls:Calendar>

            //.....My Code....  
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**DateSelection.cs**

```cs
namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class DateSelection : ContentPage
    {

        public DateSelection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        // Selecting Date
         void DateClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        /*

        Doing some operation while date selection
        */


        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like  [October 2013 is hardcoded](https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar/blob/22c5c553d23888a6b13f486e91bb8b1ec90ec184/XamForms.Controls.Calendar/Calendar.xaml#L22). But it also appears that if you set the `StartDate` property to whatever you like, it will be the date shown.

Comment: is it possible to remove the hardcoded text "OCTOBER 2013" in my project.?

Comment: Set the `TitleLabel` property to whatever you want there or like Stephane mentioned set the `StartDate` property

Comment: Scratch that last comment, looking at the code the label should update accordingly when you set the `StartDate` property

Comment: it is showing a current month in calendar even without setting the `StartDate` parameter. But initially it is showing "October 2013" as big before showing current month. So I need a empty `String` instead on `October 2013`. I have setted `TitleLabel = " "` but it is crashing the App.

Comment: is any way in `calendar` to support only future dates?. it shouldn't show previous `months`.